# Do historians distinguish between observable events vs. higher-level claims?

Tags: historiography

Modern genealogists classify information granularly, with one categorization determined by the source type (original record versus derivative copy) and another categorization determined by the informant to the information (primary, i.e., eye-witness, secondary, i.e., hearsay, or indeterminate if you don't know). They also classify evidence used in support of an argument as direct, indirect, or negative.

I have been reading some history lately, and it occurs to me that genealogists mostly deal with claims about facts that *can* be observed by a single witness and recorded, in principle. Like, "Bob Smith's mother was Mary Gates, wife of John Smith of Tuscaloosa" or "Bob Smith was born on 1 January 1870." A midwife could record either of these accurately, if one were around. But historians often have claims like, "systemic racism currently in the USA ultimately has its roots in slavery."

One might say that for the claims about Bob Smith, that they are either true or false, but in the absence of a clear-minded observer, we might never know which it is. But the claim about racism is not a claim about an event that a single observer could witness and record. It occurs to me that genealogists work almost solely with the first type of claim, and perhaps that is one of the reasons they have developed their granular distinctions.

My question: do historiographers make an analytical distinction between these two types of claims, and the evidence and analysis in each case? In particular, are there specific terms used to describe this distinction?

Prior Research: I find lots of web posts by genealogists about their own terminology. But I don’t know the terminology to search for historiography in the broad — that’s precisely what my question asks about — so I haven’t turned up anything, maybe because I don’t know the language used for this distinction

Comment: The wiki entry on the [Historical Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method) might help you with some of the terminology and techniques. The last section on [Historical Reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method#Synthesis:_historical_reasoning) deals with some of those 'higher level' arguements.

Comment: There is no "difference" of terminology, but "empirical" and "rational" words might help you. You are mixing two different things. First, there is the categorization of historical sources: This is about (real world) history, and it's not a claim, its about real world documents, statements, etc. Second, there is the proceses of synthesis and analysis in historical research: historians usually first go search about x topic (analysis), then, they process the info, summarize and reach conclusions (synthesis).

Comment: These conclusions are claims. If research is done ok, these claims are "scientific claims" (empirical is based on observations, rational if based on logic and reason). Yet, claims by historians, even after research, might be wrong. Claims by normal people might not be even based on research. For these reasons, both claims by historians and by normal people are considered secondary (or even tertiary) historical sources. Because historians do very much tend to use claims by historians that preceded them. This is probably the source of your confusion.